# INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, Account: bad field names on insert/update call: LastName, FirstName: [LastName, FirstName]ge

Tags: apex, account, person-accounts

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error:
>        INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, Account: bad field names on insert/update call: 
>       LastName, FirstName: [LastName, FirstName]

I am facing above error:

```
Account acc = new Account();
if(nameParts[0] != null)
    acc.FirstName=nameParts[0];
if(nameParts[1] != null)
    acc.LastName=nameParts[1];

acc.PersonEmail=caseObj.SuppliedEmail;                         
acc.Phone = caseObj.SuppliedPhone;
acc.recordTypeId = personAccountRecordType.Id;
```

Comment: What does contain your nameParts array? Did you activate the person account record type?

Comment: Combination of First Name and LastName, Both values are present

Comment: Please use `System.debug()` on the `nameParts` array to check the values.

Comment: I think LastName or FirstName or both coming as blank from array parsing, thats why the error is

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using the wrong record type. I verified that if you were using the correct record type, you would not receive this error. The following code works in my developer org in execute anonymous:

```
Id rtId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE IsPersonType = TRUE AND SObjectType='Account' LIMIT 1].Id;
Account a = new Account(RecordTypeId=rtId);
a.FirstName = 'Test';
a.LastName = 'Test';
insert a;
```

While the following code produced the exact error you got:

```
Id rtId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE IsPersonType = FALSE AND SObjectType='Account' LIMIT 1].Id;
Account a = new Account(RecordTypeId=rtId);
a.FirstName = 'Test';
a.LastName = 'Test';
insert a;
```

Double-check to make sure that you are using a record type that is valid for your profile, and has IsPersonType set to true.